# Generate sequence diagram while debugging in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to generate a sequence diagrams while debugging in Eclipse IDE. I have tried Diver.

Is there any other tool/plugin which helps in generating a sequence diagram?

Comment: can you explain your needs and why Diver was not sufficient ?

Comment: Diver needs the program to execute. I want to generate sequence diagram from source code, say by selecting a specific flow.

Answer (score 0):

Try [WebSequenceDiagramsForEclipse](http://1)

This does not need any program. It needs a `wsd` file to generate the diagram. You can very easily generate this file while debugging.

From the repository's readme file:

## Download

https://code.google.com/p/ewsd/downloads

## Install & Run

1. Download plug-in file.
2. Copy to your eclipse plugins directory.
3. And run eclipse.
4. create wsd file. (ex. websd.wsd)

[image: image alt]
<sub>(source: [googlecode.com](http://ewsd.googlecode.com/files/wsd-editor-screenshot-1.0.1.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this tool that I think worth trying:

https://www.maintainj.com/

Let me know if any of you guys have experienced it.
Good luck @user3760894.